# Can you reapply for a UK visa after being refused entry?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

If one is refused entry to UK for bringing more tobacco than is allowed, does he have a right to reapply for a visa? Would he be granted another visa? There is no cancelled stamp on the visa used to travel there and the person returned to India on his own ticket.

Comment: Do they really remove someone for carrying extra cigarettes? They must have concluded that the person was doing business on a visit visa and earning money in the UK

Comment: @HankyPanky He may have been refused entry for attempting to bring in a large, undeclared amount; it happens.

Comment: I have edited your question in the hopes of making it clearer. I apologize if I have misunderstood; say what is not correct.

Comment: The fact that there is no cancelled stamp on your visa doesn't mean anything. Computer records will tell all...

Answer (score 1):

You always have the right to reapply for a visa. However, your getting that visa will be influenced by the previous cancellation and how credible is the reason for your visit this time.

Answer (score 1):

The procedures and policies differ when, at the border, Her Majesty's Revenue and Customs (HMRC) makes the decision to refuse entry, rather than UKVI.

The person's biometrics would have been taken and would be kept in the system for quite a few years. Forms were provided as part of the process and would indicate any consequences, both at the time of the action and for any future applications.

Certainly a fresh visa application can be made, and judgments made could consider this refusal, along with any other previous travel history. However, no one can predict the outcome, other than to suggest that the individual's credibility has taken a hit.