# What does “voluntarily elected to depart the U.K.” mean?

Tags: uk, terminology, removal

Recently I have been refused entry to the U.K. as they were not satisfied I am a genuine visitor. Now, I would like to study in the U.K. But I'm confused as to what “voluntarily elected to depart the U.K.” means.

I was handed a Notice of Refusal of Leave to Enter. I departed the U.K. according to the instructions.

Should my answer be yes or no?

Comment: Why do you think you’ll be approved to study in the U.K. after being refused leave to enter?

Comment: @Traveller I don't think that's a helpful comment - there are lots of situations where someone might be unable to convince an IO at the airport that they should be let in, but could later successfully apply for a student visa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you reapply for a UK visa after being refused entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109395/can-you-reapply-for-a-uk-visa-after-being-refused-entry)

Comment: Can you quote the _entire_ question you're referring to with "should my answer be yes or no?" As it is you appear to be asking about a phrase that is part of such a question, but without telling us what the full question is.

Answer (score 5):

What *voluntarily elected to depart the U.K.* means is that, when you were refused entry at the border, you left and didn't make a claim that might allow temporary admission. As an aside, such temporary admission is not an immigration status and does not have any rights attached.

Your entry refusal is now part of your UK immigration record, and would be considered during application for any other visa. Your answer should be *yes*, as to do otherwise could be considered deception and a potential factor for a refusal of any subsequent visa application(s).

Answer (score -2):

Amongst other travel history-related questions UK visa application forms typically ask ‘Have you ever been... ‘refused entry at the border’. This is what happened to you, therefore in all future applications where this question is included (UK or elsewhere) you will have to answer ‘Yes’. A detailed explanation of the terms is here [Difference between deportation and removal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal/60241#60241)